# Creating text element in seperate cells across columns

Tags: javascript, html

What I am trying to do is on button press I will add 4 text elements, each text element in its own cell; beneath its corresponding column. Eg. "Name" column will have the name of the product beneath it. Refer to picture attached below.

[image]

My problem is - On button press my 4 elements are created but only one cell is created and it has all 4 of my elements in it. If someone could help me find the solution that would be amazing!

Relevant code attached below.

```
  <div id="inventory">
        <!--Here is where we shall store our data-->
       <table class="table">
        <tr class="head-row">
            <th class="table-head">Name</th>
            <th class="table-head">Price</th>
            <th class="table-head">ID</th>
            <th class="table-head">Quantity</th>
        </tr>
    <div>
```

Javascript:

```
//Items
let items = [
    ["chips",25,3163,1],
    ["Pork", 25 , 316 , 1],
    ["Crackers",5,400,1]
];
addButton.addEventListener('click', addItem);

function addItem(){

    let table = document.querySelector(".table"); 

    let row = document.createElement('tr');
    row.classList.add("row");

    let cell = document.createElement('td');
    cell.classList.add('item-properties')

    //Create our table item
    items[1].forEach(itemProperty =>{
        let textNode = document.createTextNode(itemProperty);
        cell.appendChild(textNode);
        row.appendChild(cell);
    });

    table.appendChild(row);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `td` element for each value.

```js
//Items
let items = [
  ["chips", 25, 3163, 1],
  ["Pork", 25, 316, 1],
  ["Crackers", 5, 400, 1]
];

document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('click', addItem);

function addItem() {

  let table = document.querySelector(".table");

  let row = document.createElement('tr');
  row.classList.add("row");

  let cell = document.createElement('td');
  cell.classList.add('item-properties')

  //Create our table item
  items[1].forEach(itemProperty => {
    let td = document.createElement('td');
    let textNode = document.createTextNode(itemProperty);
    td.appendChild(textNode);
    row.appendChild(td);
  });

  table.appendChild(row);
}
```

```html
<button id="add">Add</button>
<div id="inventory">
  <!--Here is where we shall store our data-->
  <table class="table">
    <tr class="head-row">
      <th class="table-head">Name</th>
      <th class="table-head">Price</th>
      <th class="table-head">ID</th>
      <th class="table-head">Quantity</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the problem all solved!

Just had to create the cell variable inside the forEach loop, so now it will loop through and create a cell each time- then add my textNode to that cell. If anyone has any pointers or alternate solutions more than happy to hear!

```
function addItem(){

    let table = document.querySelector(".table"); 

    let row = document.createElement('tr');
    row.classList.add("row");

    

    //Create our table item
    items[1].forEach(itemProperty =>{
        let textNode = document.createTextNode(itemProperty);
        cell = document.createElement('td'); //ADDED THIS
        cell.appendChild(textNode);
        row.appendChild(cell);
        console.log(itemProperty);
    });

    table.appendChild(row);
}
```